# A strange identity related to the imaginary part of the Lambert-W function

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, lambert-w

Working on a problem in QFT, i was stumbeling about some expressions containing the Lambert-$W$ function. Playing around, i discovered [experimentally](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot[ProductLog[-x],ProductLog[-1,-x],%7Bx,0,10%7D])

that the following statement seems to be true

> $$
> \Im (W_0(-x))=-\Im (W_{-1}(-x))\,\,\, \text{if} \,\,\, x>1/e
> $$

For large $x$ we can write

$W_0(-x)\approx\log(-x)$

and

$W_{-1}(-x)\approx\log(-x)-2 \pi i$

choosing now $\log(-x)=\pi i+\log(x)$

gives the desired result in this limit (but to be honest i don't see why this choice is the right one).

My question is now:

> How can we prove the above statement? And (as a bonus) are there some additional relations like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$W_0(-x)$ and $W_{-1}(-x)$ are both solution of the equation :
$$we^w=-x$$
Let $w=a+ib$ then
$$\begin{cases}
a e^a \cos(b)-b e^a \sin(b) = -x \\
i\left(a e^a \sin(b)+b e^a \cos(b)\right) = 0 \\
\end{cases}$$
where $x\:,\:a\:,\:b$ are reals.

The system of equations is valid for the two considered solutions with a same couple $(a,b)$, but $i$ and $-i$ respectively.

Thus, two solutions are : 
$\quad \begin{cases}
W_0(-x) = a+ib \\
W_{-1}(-x) = a-ib \\
\end{cases}$

$W_0(-x)$ and $W_{-1}(-x)$ are conjugates : 
$\begin{cases}
\Re (W_0(-x))=\Re (W_{-1}(-x))\\
\Im (W_0(-x))=-\Im (W_{-1}(-x))\\
\end{cases}$
$\quad x>\frac{1}{e}$

Comment: Thanks! Don't know why i haven't seen this by myself..